# Can I get the Immortal Photobomb achievement after completing the main story?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm trying to get the "Immortal Photobomb" achievement, but I never paid attention to the fact that Gentiana could be in Prompto's photos until now.

However, I've already completed the main story and am at Chapter 15.

My question is: Can Gentiana appear on random photos at chapter 15 (that is, *after* I've completed the main story?

*---EDIT---* I finally got it at chapter 15 so I confirm that this trophy cannot be missed.

Comment: Its possible you've already got a photo anyway.  [Trueachievements](https://www.trueachievements.com/a226626/immortal-photobomb-achievement) says its fairly easy to get through regular play.  Can't you just look through the photos you already have to see if the achievement unlocks?

Comment: @TimmyJim, unfortunately, you can only save 150 pictures total during any given playthrough. If OP didnt save any of the pictures with Gentiana, then he wouldn't be able to get the achievement by looking at their past pictures. It's entirely possible OP neglected to look at pictures with her in them before deleting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to get this achievement at any point after meeting Gentiana.

From [this achievement guide](https://www.trueachievements.com/a226626/immortal-photobomb-achievement):

> This achievement requires you to get a photo of Gentiana, Luna's divine helper, who starts speaking to Noctis in Chapter 5. Getting said photo relies entirely on Prompto and his random picture-taking.
>
> Gentiana will appear in photos at random, without actually having been present when they were taken. No need to replay her scripted appearances.
>
> However, going from the official guide, there are some requirements and ways to increase your chances at it. First, the picture can apparently only be taken after you have completed the Trial of Ramuh in Chapter 5. And finally, the chances for the picture to be taken apparently increase the longer your party stays awake. The longer you go without resting at a hotel or camp, the higher your odds are for getting the picture.
>
> That being said, this should easily be gained through normal play. The chances are high enough already. I ended up getting probably 6 or 7 photos of her as I played through the story.

Others have confirmed that you can get this achievement after completing this game. See [this thread](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/final-fantasy-xv/300724-immortal-photobomb.html):

> You can't get it until after chapter 4 or 5, but not it's not missable. **You can still get it post game.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

From personal experience, I believe I've gotten at least one Immortal Photobomb-eligible picture (though I got the trophy quite early on) after completing the game, during my trophy cleanup.

Answer (score -2):

No. From my experience in four play-throughs:

> Once Shiva has been revealed her alter ego no longer appears in the correct time-space.

Using Umbra and going back in time does not work either but NG+ will give another opportunity to earn this trophy / achievement.

Comment: This is inaccruate. I get a gentiana photo about 1 in every 30 photos taken

Comment: And yet in my four consecutive play-throughs and more than 1000 photos taken, not once did Gentiana photobomb in Chapter 15 as the question asks, and not once did she photobomb when I went back in time after she reveals herself as Shiva. Odd.

Comment: Maybe i got really lucky, or you got really unlucky. I see her ALL the time while running around in chapter 15 lol. You do have to scan through the photos, to have them mention her, nothing else special happens. Did you always scan thru them when you camped?

Comment: Well, I did not zoomed on every photos. Just the one I wanted to keep but she never appeared on these, guess I was unlucky. Is she going to appear if I go back in time to complete other trophies or even take a photo of Shiva in fight?

Comment: Idk about the shiva fight, but i have seen her pop up no less then 10 times while finishing things in chapter 15. If you havent already, i would check your achievments to confirm you dont already have it. When i started to think about trophy hunting after i beat the game, i came across this one and wasnt happy cause i had no control over when it happens, but found I already had it done.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a screen cap of that